# Update previous rows using the successive rows values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains the following details

| cust_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01-01-2019 | 31-12-1999 |
| 111 | 02-01-2021 | 31-12-1999 |
| 111 | 03-01-2022 | 31-12-1999 |
| 112 | 12-13-2019 | 31-12-1999 |
| 112 | 07-22-2020 | 31-12-1999 |

For every Id in the table, I would like to update the end_date field of each row with the start_date value of next row. The update should happen based on the id's only.

Here is the format of the output that I want:

| cust_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01-01-2019 | 02-01-2021 |
| 111 | 02-01-2021 | 03-01-2022 |
| 111 | 03-01-2022 | NULL |
| 112 | 12-13-2019 | 07-22-2020 |
| 112 | 07-22-2020 | NULL |

I tried writing the following query, but it didn't work.

```
with 
my_cte (cust_id, start_date, end_date, rn)(
select cust_id, start_date, end_date, row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by cust_id) rn from locations;
)
update locations set end_date = (select start_date from my_cte where my_cte.rn=max(rn)) where cust_id = my_cte.cust_id;
```

Could anyone please help

Comment: How can end_date be before start_date?

Comment: Your dates don't appear to be dates and the format is inconsistent eg 12-13-2019 looks like m/d/y  31-12-1999 looks like d/m/y  - you should start by clarifying this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this,

```
with my_cte (cust_id, start_date, end_date, rn) as (
select cust_id, start_date, end_date
, lead(start_date) over(partition by cust_id order by start_date) rn 
from locations
)
update locations set end_date = 
(select  min(rn) from my_cte 
where locations.cust_id = my_cte.cust_id and 
locations.start_date=my_cte.start_date);
```